# Getting "Unable to authenticate the supplied URL" authentication error on using clientId & signature in google geocoding URL

Tags: google-geocoding-api

We are porting from version 2 to version 3 of geocoding api. This public [url](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=27606&sensor=false) works but is limited to 2500 requests per day & we are a business user so we need to use `clientId` & `signature` parameters as well in the url. We have the `clientId` given by google and we are generating the `signature` using this [code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices#JavaSignatureExample) provided by google itself.

*Note: version 2 required us to use the "key" directly but in version we need to generate the signature and use that instead of the key !*

But after generating the signature & appending the clientId & signature to the url e.g.

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=27606&sensor=false&client=<OUR_CLIENT_ID>&signature=<SIGNATURE_WE_GENERATE>`we are getting this message `Unable to authenticate the supplied URL. Please check your client and signature parameters.` instead.

Any idea what is wrong with the way we are generating the signature? We are directly using the sample signature generating code given above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the steps I was following were correct, but the 'YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY' that we were using to generate the signed_url in the java code given by google, was incorrect. We gave the correct private key to the code & it generated a correct signature that works now.

Answer (score 0):

I once experienced same error.

I was using 2 keys
- one for development (Key for browser apps with referer: Any referer allowed) 
- one for server (Key for browser apps with referer:  referer = my server's domain)

One day, I started to get this error (Unable to authenticate the supplied URL) on my dev VBox, for some of the Gooble API calls (like routes), but strangely enough not all the APIs.
I solved it by adding localhost to my server's authorised referers and using same key for both dev & prod.
I can't tell much more as understanding what the problem was wasn't my highest priority as soon as I had a workaround, but I hope this can help you to solve your own issue.